# Getting pointer to boost::any::operator=

Tags: c++, boost, pointer-to-member

I want to get pointer to boost::any::operator=, so i did this:

```
bool(__thiscall boost::any::*func)(const bool&) = &(boost::any::operator=<bool>);
```

but now, compiler says

initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'bool (__thiscall boost::any::* )(const bool &)'
        None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

i also tried to make it this way:

```
bool(__thiscall boost::any::*func)(const bool&) = static_cast<(boost::any::*)(const bool&)>(&(boost::any::operator=<bool>));
```

but there is compiler says: "syntax error : '('" in this line

can anybody helps me, please?

P.S. I make instaces of boost::any in the code above

Comment: There are different variants of operator= available in boost::any     any & operator=(const any &);  any & operator=(any &&);  template<typename ValueType> any & operator=(const ValueType &);  template<typename ValueType> any & operator=(ValueType &&); Which one you're trying to get an address of? The error is probably because of wrong assignment to function pointer

Comment: I trying to get adress of 
template<typename ValueType> any & operator=(const ValueType & rhs);
for bool, int and double. So, how i must make this assingment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify the arguments in the assignment of the member function pointer.
This will do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::any any = false;
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<bool>(any) << std::endl;
    typedef boost::any& (boost::any::*assign_operator)(const bool&);
    assign_operator assign = &boost::any::operator =;
    (any.*assign)(true);
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<bool>(any) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```